# php regex too strict

Tags: php

Just wondering why this is too strict, I can send very simplified emails to say tim@yahoo.com or two@google.com

but if I make the email any longer (sacagawea@gmail.com) it does not get sent.

Instead it echos back my error message:Invalid Email Address Supplied

```
    // Create a function to check email 
function checkEmail($email)
{
// Add some regex 
  return preg_match('/^\S+@[\w\d.-]{2,}\.[\w]{2,6}$/iU', $email) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `cond ? TRUE : FALSE` when just `cond` will do.

Comment: Thank you, sorry did not see catch that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part

```
@[\w\d.-]{2,}
```

is gobbling up

```
@gmail.com
```

leaving nothing for this part

```
[\w\d.-]{2,}
```

to match.

Better to reuse something already proven, see for example http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, Just wondering  does  Ctrl+F on your keyboard use some type of regex to find stuff, I think so, it even has the option to Match a case, but they don't call it regex, just Find?

Comment: Huh?  The behaviour of Ctrl+F depends entirely on which application receives those keys when I hit them.

Comment: I just meant the way it uses certain matches, even if it's a web browser, word doc, command prompt, shell console, or notepad++, or just grepping.

Comment: Isn't the objective  usually to match a given case and do something with the matched data right?
Block or allow certain emails or replace certain words, rename directories, etc?

Comment: @Newb - OK let me take wild guess at what you're asking.  You're asking if all FIND operations use RegEx?  The answer is no. Why should they? If I want to search for string "hola" in a file containing "abc hold hole hulk holabc" I can just look for the string itself, no Regex magic required.  RegEx allows you (the developer) to search for a variety of strings using one expression (the regex) instead of many expressions (literal strings).  Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Thanks for the info edg, yes, that's what I was asking.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to php 5.2 or above, you should use the [filter](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.filter.php) functions :

```
function checkEmail($email){
  return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false;
}
```

Or validate it, "[the right way](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585)".

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't fret myself too much for checking email validity. I just need to check there is a value in front of "@" and at the back. That's all. The rest of the "checking" job, the MTAs will do that for me. If its invalid email, i will get a response from MTA. If its able to be sent out, that means the email is most probably valid.

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
'/^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+$/'
```

it also fits for subdomain email adresses as `email@sub.domain.tl`